# Prestashop 1.7 request carrier less price in product.tpl

Tags: prestashop

I am trying to make the right request to recover the cheapest carriers that I would like to display in the product sheet.

Thank you for help

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Nothing for the moment on the product sheet I thought to do a function with a request but I would like to make a clean request according to id_shop and id_lang

Comment: think about this too: user not logged have no delivery address so, you can only get the cheapest carrier price for customer with address. look at the carrier class method getDeliveryPriceByWeight : Carrier::getDeliveryPriceByWeight($product_weight, $carrier_zone)